# How to override the automatically created docstring data for Boost::Python?

Tags: c++, python, boost, documentation, boost-python

I am currently working developing a C++-based module for Python.  I have found that Boost::Python is working quite well for what I want to accomplish.  However, I am now running into some issues with the docstring that is being generated by Boost::Python.  Given the following Boost::Python definitions:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(gcsmt)
{
class_<gcsmt::Units>("Units", "Sets the units used as input.", no_init)
    .def("PrintSupported", &gcsmt::Units::printSupported, "Print out all supported units.")
    .def("SetDefault", &gcsmt::Units::setDefaultUnit, "Sets the default unit to be used for inputs/outputs.")
    .staticmethod("PrintSupported")
    .staticmethod("SetDefault")
    .def(self_ns::str(self_ns::self))
    ;
}
```

If I compile, load my module in Python, and get help on the gscmt.Units class, the output is the following:

```
>>> help(gcsmt.Units)

Help on class Units in module gcsmt:

class Units(Boost.Python.instance)
 |  Sets the units used as input.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Units
 |      Boost.Python.instance
 |      __builtin__.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __reduce__ = <unnamed Boost.Python function>(...)
 |  
 |  __str__(...)
 |      __str__( (Units)arg1) -> object :
 |      
 |          C++ signature :
 |              _object* __str__(gcsmt::Units {lvalue})
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Static methods defined here:
 |  
 |  PrintSupported(...)
 |      PrintSupported() -> None :
 |          Print out all supported units.
 |      
 |          C++ signature :
 |              void PrintSupported()
 |  
 |  SetDefault(...)
 |      SetDefault( (UnitType)arg1, (str)arg2) -> None :
 |          Sets the default unit to be used for inputs/outputs.
 |      
 |          C++ signature :
 |              void SetDefault(gcsmt::unitType,std::string)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__ = <built-in function __init__>
 |      Raises an exception
 |      This class cannot be instantiated from Python
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Boost.Python.instance:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from Boost.Python.instance:
 |  
 |  __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of Boost.Python.class object>
 |      T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T
```

While much of the documentation being output is valuable to me as a developer, most of it would be noise, or even worse, confusing, to an end user.  (E.g.- my users don't care what the C++ signature of a given method is, nor do they need to see the Method resolution order, or additional hidden methods that are shown).  Is there any way to override, and reduce the level/verbosity of the documentation set up by Boost::Python?  Ideally, I'd like my documentation to look something like:

```
>>> help(gcsmt.Units)

Help on class Units in module gcsmt:

class Units
 |  Sets the units used as input.
 |  
 |  PrintSupported() -> None :
 |      Print out all supported units.
 |  
 |  SetDefault( (UnitType)arg1, (str)arg2) -> None :
 |      Sets the default unit to be used for inputs/outputs.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Use the **boost::python::docstring_options** class to define your auto-created docstring options.
- All **def** functions take a docstring as the last parameter.
- All **class_** definitions take the class docstring as the last parameter

I.e.:

```
using boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
  // This will enable user-defined docstrings and python signatures,
  // while disabling the C++ signatures
  docstring_options local_docstring_options(true, true, false);

  class_<Bar>("Bar", init<>(), "Bar class" /* class docstring here */ )
    .def("foobar", &Bar::foobar, "foobar function" /* function docstring here */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks aleksey.  The docstring_options got me most of the way there.  It looks like the help module in python adds a bunch of extra info to classes, but that looks like it isn't a boost issue.

Comment: `docstring_options` is a class that overrides the options in the ctor and restores them in the dtor, effectively changing the options in the current scope.  Therefore it does not suffice to create a temporary `docstring_options`, you must create a local variable to keep it alive, e.g. `docstring_options doc_opts(true, true, false);`.

Comment: still a useful answer in 2017.  note that the docstrings for `class_` are slightly different than above.  it goes `class_<T>("PyName","class docstring",init<>(), "Init docstring")`.  see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/class)

Comment: my previous comment was indicating that this answer is useful, but i meant at that time for the ordering of arguments to `class_`.  regarding turning off C++ signatures, I just tried this answer to no avail.

Comment: however, by inspecting [minieigen](https://github.com/eudoxos/minieigen), i was able to see that `docstring_options docopt;
   docopt.enable_all();
   docopt.disable_cpp_signatures();` is what i needed, and confirmed works