# Setting different doc string for functions of the same custom type defined with Python-C-API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm embedding python in a C++ application and wrote a function wrapper (like `boost::python` does). To achieve this, I created a custom python type and defined its `PyTypeObject` structure and set a `tp_call` function pointer.

This works fine, but now I would like to be able to set the documentation of the wrapped functions. For the moment, when I run `help(some_function)` in the Python interpreter, a generic documentation is printed. Setting `tp_doc` of the `PyTypeObject` structure doesn't help since it provides the same help string for all the wrapped functions.

I also tried to call

```
PyObject_SetAttrString((PyObject*)a_wrapped_function, "__doc__", PyUnicode_FromString("some doc"))
```

but this call returns -1, which means failure (this attribute is probably considered read-only).

I considered creating a new `PyTypeObject` for each wrapped function, but I didn't tried yet since I think this may be overkill...

Is there a nice way to tell Python the doc string to be returned for each wrapped function ?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114462/how-to-override-the-automatically-created-docstring-data-for-boostpython

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a way. Just follow the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMethodDef

Basically what you need to do is this:

```
static PyMethodDef YourMethods[] = {
  { "yourMethod", yourMethod, METH_NOARGS, 
    "Your docstring for the method/function." },
   0};
```

And then just include `YourMethods` in your `PyModuleDef`, and that's it.